# Echo PHP message after AJAX success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a modal that will display when the user clicks a delete button. Once they hit the delete button I am using AJAX to subimit the form. Eveything works fine, but it is not display my success message which is set in PHP.

Here is my AJAX code:

```
function deleteUser(){
    var id = <?php echo $userdetails['id'] ?>;  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'admin_user.php?id=' + id,
        data: $('form.adminUser').serialize(),
        error: function(e){
                alert(e);
            },
        success: function () {
           // This is empty because i don't know what to put here.
        }
    }); 
}
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
if ($deletion_count = deleteUsers($deletions)) {
        $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_DELETIONS_SUCCESSFUL", array($deletion_count));
    } else {
        $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
    }
```

And then I call it like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="resultBlock">
   <?php echo resultBlock($errors,$successes); ?>
</div>
```

When I use AJAX it does not display the message. This works fine on other pages that does not require AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: Your success function is empty. Where do you expect the message to be automatically displayed?

Comment: your header() call is pointless. even if it did work, you wouldn't be redirecting the user's browser, you'd be redirecting the ajax request, which the user would never see.

Comment: @Popnoodles I don't know what should go in the success function. I update the code above to show where the message would be displayed. Basically at the top of the page in a div.

Comment: @MarcB I wanted to display the message on the page then redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with how AJAX works, the PHP script you call will not directly output to the page, consider the below simplified lifecycle of an AJAX request:

```
Main Page -> Submit Form -> Put form data into array
          |
          --> Send array to a script to be processed on the server
          |
          |----> Callback from the server script to modify DOM (or whatever you want to do)
```

There are many callbacks, but here lets discuss `success` and `error`

If your PHP script was not found on the server or there was any other internal error, an `error` callback is returned, else a `success` callback is fired, in jQuery you can specify a data array to be received in your callback - this contains any data echoed from your PHP script.

In your case, you should amend your PHP file to echo your arrays, this means that if a successful request is made, the `$successes` or `$errors` array is echoed back to the data parameter of your AJAX call

```
if ($deletion_count = deleteUsers($deletions)) {
    $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_DELETIONS_SUCCESSFUL", array($deletion_count));
    echo $successes;
} else {
    $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
    echo $errors;
}
```

You can then test you received an object by logging it to the console:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: It is still loading the whole page html in the alert.

Comment: I made a few edits, but based on your comment I was able to modify it a bit. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I want to do the right thing so I'm not sure if I should mark your answer as the correct one or not?

Comment: If you feel that my answer pointed you toward your solution then accepting it as the correct answer would be great

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite not clear what does work and what does not work, but two things are bothering me : the function for success in Ajax is empty and you have a *header* function making a refresh in case of success. Have you tried removing the *header* function ?

Comment: Yes, i removed it and it still doesn't work. The reason why the success function is empty is because i don't know what to put there to display the the php error in the bootstrap alert div.

Comment: Well just do something like `$('#idofyourdiv').html(data) ;` with the good values. You should check the different prototypes possible for the success function to know how to get the data your php script answered . You should also use the network analyzer (available in Chrome -> Tools -> Developper Tools) to see what your PHP does return.

Comment: Technically that worked that problem is `data` is outputting the entire page again. How can I just display this `resultBlock($errors,$successes);`

Comment: Well, how would you know the data has been requested by Ajax and not by visiting the page directly ?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean. When I look at the POST response using Firebug it shows that the alert is there, but it is not displaying on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
}
```

In case of success this would alert the data that is echoed on the php page. That's how it works. 
I'm using this a lot when I'm using $.post

Your header will not do anything. You'll have to show the data on the Java script side, maybe with alert, and then afterwards redirect the user to where you want in javascript.

Comment: I don't want to use an alert. I want it to be displayed in the bootstrap alert div and then redirect that is why i used the header. I have removed it because it seems that everyone is focusing on the wrong thing here.

Answer (score 0):

you need put some var in success function

```
success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
}
```

then, when you read var "data" u can do anything with the text

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I changed the PHP to:

```
if ($deletion_count = deleteUsers($deletions)) {
        $successes[] = lang("ACCOUNT_DELETIONS_SUCCESSFUL", array($deletion_count));
        echo resultBlock($errors,$successes);
    } else {
        $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
        echo resultBlock($errors,$successes);
    }
```

And the I changed the AJAX to this:

```
function deleteUser(){
    var id = <?php echo $userdetails['id'] ?>;      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'admin_user.php?id=' + id,
        data: $('form.adminUser').serialize(),
        error: function(e){
                alert(e);
            },
        success: function (data) {
            result = $(data).find("#success");       
            $('#resultBlock').html(result);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Because data was loading all html I had to find exactly what I was looking for out of the HTMl so that is why I did `.find`.